# Tool to draw neural network directed graphs

Tags: graphical-model

I would like to reproduce the kind of graphs used in the book *Deep learning*. Do you know the tool which can do that kind of graphs? Ideally I would like the apparence to be exactly the same.

Here is an example of Recurrent neural network graph:

[image: RNN]

Comment: There was a talk on this by Piotr Migdał on PyData Berlin 2018 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhHkiglbnBQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[yed](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) is a very convenient tool for drawing graphs, but I'm not aware that it's able to do math mode.

Not really convenient, but very powerful, is the [tikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/flowcharts/) package from Latex.